# ROS2 environment variables

Tags: ros, ros2, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I was building ROS2 from source and I already had kinetic installed on my system.
After following all the instructions [here](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Linux-Development-Setup#alternative-dds-sources), I tried to see my environment variables to check if everything was fine(as I did with each distro of ROS1) but I got this output :

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/batman/rosbuild-packages:/home/batman/catkin_ws/install/share:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.88.10:11311
ROS_VERSION=2
ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT=${message}
ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.88.223
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_DISTRO=ardent
ROS_IP=192.168.88.223
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

Here I can see the `ROS_VERSION` as 2 and the distro variable as ardent but the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and `ROS_ROOT` is still set according to kinetic. Do I need to change that, if yes how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290877/ros2-environment-variables/) by [aarushg](https://answers.ros.org/users/35073/aarushg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2018-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all you should not source *both* setup files if you don't have to (e.g. for building something like the `ros1_bridge`). Commonly you should only source one of the two. Otherwise you will likely run into problems where some packages (e.g. `std_msgs`) exist in both ROS versions.

Regarding the questions about `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and `ROS_ROOT` (and several others like `ROS_MASTER_URI`, `ROS_HOSTNAME`, `ROS_IP`): ROS 2 doesn't use either of these variables.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarushg](https://answers.ros.org/users/35073/aarushg/) on 2018-05-11**:
Thanks!
But since I was using kinetic since a long time, it was already sourced, so is there a way to unsource it(reset every variable) before sourcing ros2 or the only way is to unset/remove the unrequired variables of ros1 individually?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-05-11**:
Rather than trying to unset variables / modify the ones which have been changed by the setup script you might want to open a fresh shell (assuming that you don't source the setup file in your bashrc). If you do I would recommend to define an alias instead and explicitly call the alias to source ROS.